# Xunit For Attach in EF causing null reference exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, moq, xunit

I am trying to write xUnit for my update service, but I get a null reference exception

```
    public bool Update(string Id, CreateUpdateUserDto InP)
    {
        var user = new UserDetails
        {
            Id = Id,
            Name = InP.Name
        };
        _dbContext.userDetails.Attach(user);
        _dbContext.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges() > 0;
    }
```

I have written a test case like this:

```
    private readonly Mock<UserDbContext> _mockDB;
    private UserRepository _repo;

    public UserRepositoryTests()
    {
        var data = new List<UserDetails>
        {
            new UserDetails{Id="GuId1",Name="Test1"},
            new UserDetails{Id="GuId2",Name="Test2"},
            new UserDetails{Id="GuId3",Name="Test3"}
        }.AsQueryable();
        var mockSet = new Mock<DbSet<UserDetails>>();
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserDetails>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(data.Provider);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserDetails>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(data.Expression);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserDetails>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(data.ElementType);
        mockSet.As<IQueryable<UserDetails>>().Setup(x => x.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => data.GetEnumerator());

        _mockDB = new Mock<UserDbContext>();
        _mockDB.Setup(y=>y.userDetails).Returns(mockSet.Object);


        _repo = new UserRepository(_mockDB.Object);
    }

    [Fact]
    public void UpdateSuccess()
    {
        var InP = new CreateUpdateUserDto()
        {
            Name = "Test"
        };
        var result = _repo.Update("GuId1", InP);
        Assert.IsType<bool>(result);
        Assert.True(result);
    }
```

I'm getting this error:

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>
> Stack Trace: 
> UserRepository.Update(String Id, CreateUpdateUserDto InP) line 35
> UserRepositoryTests.UpdateSuccess() line 71

Line No 71 is

```
_dbContext.Entry(user).Property(x => x.Name).IsModified = true;
```

I am not getting how to mock it

[GIT Repo](https://github.com/upendarreddy678/XUnit-Test-API)

Comment: Provided GIT Repository which is public

Answer (score 0):

Your `_mockDB` is mocked and not a real implementation of `DbContext`

`_dbContext.Entry(..)` is not implemented and will return null and thus calling `_dbContext.Entry(user).Property(..)` is causing your nullref.

You're also going to have to implement SaveChanges, and your EntityEntry.Property (when mocking EntityEntry)

Sidenote: perhaps it's better to [reconsider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/choosing-a-testing-strategy) your testing strategy, as mocking an ORM can be very difficult/time-consuming.

Comment: Can you suggest me how to mock it.is it possible to mock Entry